# Translate string from sxw file

Tags: odoo

I would like to translate raw strings I added in the sxw `Invoice` report.

Former string from this report such as `Taxes` are translated, but I don't know how to translate 'raw strings' associated to custom field I added to the model `Invoice`...

Even some native model field label in the sxw report, such as `account.invoice.date_due` are not translated anymore. I don't understand why.

Thank you for your help

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Look for the file corresponding to your language in the **addons/account/i18n/** folder. I suppose you'll discover that some texts from the existing installation are not translated and obviously your new fields descriptions are also missing.

You may want to take a look here too: https://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/contribute/07_improving_translations.html/#translations-code

Comment: Thanks Andrei for your help. I've taken a look to `addons/account/i18n/fr.po`, but none of my string added in the report appears in the po file. I even synchronized language term from erp, and thoroughly look into `Applications Terms -> Translated Terms` to find my new string but nothing to see!

Comment: You have to add your strings by yourself in the .po file

Comment: The string which is not translated is 'Due Date' for instance in the sxw file. In the po file I have `#. module: account ... #: field:report.invoice.created,date_due:0 ... msgid "Due Date"
msgstr "Date d'échéance"`. What else should I add ? cheers

Comment: I can see now the string Due Date translated, but did nothing since yesterday except another (among many) synch from the admin interface... Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure but it's possible that you have to either update the account module with the -u command line options ot update the module installation trough the admin interface. May be this was the reason...